# On the period of Bell numbers modulo a prime

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic, solution-verification, bell-numbers

Like my recent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3358291), this one is related to the [conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Modular_arithmetic) stating that, for a prime $p$, the (exact) period of $n\mapsto B_n\bmod p$ is equal to $(p^p-1)/(p-1)$. That question covers a test whether a positive integer $m$ is a period: it suffices to check $B_{m+n}\equiv B_n\pmod{p}$ for $0\leqslant n<p$.

I've found, as it seems, a simpler test (let's denote by $\mathbb{F}_p$ the field $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$):

> An $m>0$ is a period of $n\mapsto B_n\bmod p\ $ if and only if $\ x^p-x-1$ divides $x^m-1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.

Compared to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3358321), where I suggest to compute $T=S^m\bmod(S^p-S-1,p)$, and apply it to the initial $p$ values of $B_n\bmod p$ (which require a dedicated computation) with $S$ sending $B_n$ to $B_{n+1}$ (basically, this is a convolution computation), the above suggests just to check $T=1$.

My proof considers the formal power series [$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B_n x^n$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/172955) over $\mathbb{F}_p$, i.e. as an element of $\mathbb{F}_p[[x]]$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B_n x^n&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{x}{1-kx}=\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}\sum_{r=0}^{p-1}\prod_{k=1}^{pq+r}\frac{x}{1-kx}\\&=\left[\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{p}\frac{x}{1-kx}\right)^q\right]\left[\sum_{r=0}^{p-1}\prod_{k=1}^{r}\frac{x}{1-kx}\right]\\&=\left[\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^p}{1-x^{p-1}}\right)^q\right]\left[\sum_{r=0}^{p-1}\prod_{k=1}^{r}\frac{x}{1-kx}\right]\\&=\frac{1-x^{p-1}}{1-x^{p-1}-x^p}\sum_{r=0}^{p-1}\prod_{k=1}^{r}\frac{x}{1-kx}=\frac{N_p(x)}{D_p(x)},
\end{align}
where $N_p(x)=\sum\limits_{r=0}^{p-1}x^r\prod\limits_{k=r+1}^{p-1}(1-kx)$ is a polynomial of degree $<p$, and $D_p(x)=1-x^{p-1}-x^p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$ (for this, it suffices to check $D_p(x)\mid x^{p^p}-x$; let's omit the details). On the other hand, if $m$ is a period, then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B_n x^n=(\sum_{n=0}^{m-1}B_n x^n)/(1-x^m)$, and thus $D_p(x)$ divides $(1-x^m)N_p(x)$, hence it divides $1-x^m$. [Reflecting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial), we're done with $\implies$ (the $\impliedby$ is easier).

[We could guess $D_p$ from Touchard's congruence, and in fact don't need $N_p$ explicitly.]

Now the **question**. Is the above correct? If it is (as I hope), does it bring us closer to resolution?

**Update.** Found in the second of the articles given in the comment by Gerry Myerson. (At least it is stated there; I didn't track its history back yet.)

Comment: Are you familiar with Wagstaff, Aurifeuillian factorizations and the period of Bell numbers modulo a prime, Math Comp 65 (1996) 383-391? Gallardo and Rahavandrainy, Bell numbers modulo a prime number, traces and trinomials, Elec J Combin 21 (2014) #P4.49? Montgomery et al., The period of Bell numbers modulo a prime, Math Comp? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2908369/bell-number-modulo-prime-power ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thanks for the second one! ("Yes" for the other two - in fact the first one was "the point of departure" for me. The MSE questions don't look very relevant, though the [article](https://www.emis.de/journals/BBMS/Bulletin/bul964/Robert-Gertsch.pdf) mentioned in the comments there is of some interest.)